# How do I dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I had Ubuntu on my computer and then I reinstalled Windows 7 and now the Grub mean is gone from start up. I can't remember how I did it last time.

I am on Windows 7 right now and need to know if I can do it from here or if I have to get onto Ubuntu to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can restore your Grub without re-installing Ubuntu

Here's a refrence for you

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows